# JPA / Spring MVC Rest API - One to Many relation in the same Entity

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I began 2 days ago to use Spring MVC and I meet some issues with a case study. 
**I created a basic table categories (category_id refers to a category id):**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `categories`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_CATEGORY_CATEGORY` (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `categories`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_CATEGORY_CATEGORY` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`);
```

Now my issue is to display the full list of categories with their children if they exist ...

**I have in my controller this method which returns a list in JSON :**

```
@GetMapping(path="/categories", produces= {"application/json"})
    public List<Category> getAllCategories(Model model) {
        return categoryRepository.findAll();
}
```

It is recommended to do this :

```
public class Category implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private Category parentCategory;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parentCategory", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Category> childCategories;


    ... default constructor, getters & setter etc.
}
```

While trying to view the page i can see the categories but i don't display if they have subcategories or not .... For example this category shoud give a list of children categories ... For example i shoud have in child categories id = 5, name = ..., etc., id =6, id = 7...

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "XXX",
    "createdat": 1541872732000,
    "updatedat": 1541872732000,
    "parentCategory": null,
    "childCategories": [

    ]
 ....
}
```

and this category who have a parent category returns no parent whereas the parentCategory value should be 1 :

```
  {
    "id": 14,
    "name": "xxxxxx",
    "createdat": 1541873447000,
    "updatedat": 1541873447000,
    "parentCategory": null,
    "childCategories": [

    ]
 ....
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When are you fetching child entities?

Comment: Did u try :
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true

Comment: The child entities are present in the entity itself ... For example an item with ID:1 have children with ID=16 and in the database it would result id: 16, category_id:1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution i found :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="categories")
@NamedQuery(name="Category.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Category c")
public class Category implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="category_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Category parentCategory;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parentCategory", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Category> childCategory;

    public Category() {
    }

    public Category(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    // getters & setters
}
```